# A question from Gathmann's notes on Algebraic Geometry.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is question from [Gathmann's notes](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/main.pdf) on Algebraic Geometry.

Let $$C_n=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{C}^2;y^2=(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-2n)\}\subset\Bbb{C}^2$$

Gathmann says that if we go in a circle around any of the points $1,2,3\dots,n$, "we go from one copy of the plane to another".

I don't know what that means. $y$ clearly has two values for every single value of $x$. So this might mean that we travel from one value of $y$ to another. I can picture this happening for the polynomial $C_1$, but the picture is too complicated for me for $C_r$ where $r>1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p\in C_n$ be a point with $y=0,$ i.e. $p=(k,0)$ for some $k=1,\ldots,2n$. In a small neighborhood $U$ around $p$, all the terms $(x-1),\ldots,(x-2n)$, except for $(x-k)$ don't change dramatically, so inside $U$ $C_n$ actually looks pretty much like $C_1$.

Comment: Doesn't $y=0$ imply $y=(0,0)$, and not $(k,0)$?

Comment: I just meant that $(k,0)$ would satisfy the equation for instance, where $y=0$. $y\neq (k,0)$. Thanks for your answer. Correcting that minor glitch would be useful for all future readers.

Comment: Right, I hadn't  noticed my typo. It's corrected now, thanks. Is the answer clear?